# Number of Ways in a Given maze from start to end

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search

So I am trying to find how many ways exist in a given maze from start to end.

Here is my code, using Depth first search.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class NumberofWaysInAMaze {
class VisitedNode
{
    private int x;
    private int y;


    public VisitedNode(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

public int findNumberofWaysToMaze(boolean[][] maze, int targetX, int targetY)
{
    int numberofWays = 0;
    int rows = maze.length;
    int columns = maze[0].length;
    boolean[][] visitedMap = new boolean[rows][columns];
    for(int i=0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        System.arraycopy(maze[i], 0, visitedMap[i], 0, maze[i].length);
    }

    Stack<VisitedNode> stack = new Stack<VisitedNode>();

    VisitedNode root = new VisitedNode(0, 0);
    stack.push(root);

    while(!stack.empty())
    {
        VisitedNode visitingNode = stack.pop();
        int currentX = visitingNode.x;
        int currentY = visitingNode.y;
        if(currentX == targetX && currentY == targetY)
        {
            numberofWays++;
        }else

        {//System.out.println("x is:" + currentX + "--- y is:" + currentY);
        visitedMap[currentX][currentY] = true;
        }
        if(currentX+1 <= targetX && currentX+1 >= 0 && visitedMap[currentX+1][currentY] == false && maze[currentX+1][currentY] == false)
        {
            stack.push(new VisitedNode(currentX+1, currentY));
        }

        if(currentX-1 <= targetX && currentX-1 >= 0 && visitedMap[currentX-1][currentY] == false && maze[currentX-1][currentY] == false)
        {
            stack.push(new VisitedNode(currentX-1, currentY));
        }

        if(currentY+1 <= targetY && currentY+1 >= 0 && visitedMap[currentX][currentY+1] == false && maze[currentX][currentY+1] == false)
        {
            stack.push(new VisitedNode(currentX, currentY+1));
        }

        if(currentY-1 <= targetY && currentY-1 >= 0 && visitedMap[currentX][currentY-1] == false && maze[currentX][currentY-1] == false)
        {
            stack.push(new VisitedNode(currentX, currentY-1));
        }

    }

    return numberofWays;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    NumberofWaysInAMaze test = new NumberofWaysInAMaze();
    boolean[][] maze = 
            {
             {false, false, false, false, false},
             {false, true, false, true, false},
             {false, true, false, true, false},
             {false, true, false, true, false},
             {false, false, false, false, false},
            };
    System.out.println(test.findNumberofWaysToMaze(maze, 4, 4));
}
```

}

However, the output is not right. My output is 2 and obviously, there are four ways in the given maze(false means OK to pass and true means Block). I know the reason is because I use another 2D array to record whether a point has been visited. However, I don't know how I can modify my solution. Any comments or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What are the four paths? I see five (so I must be getting it wrong).

Comment: @acdcjunior Head right, head right taking the middle, head down, head down taking the middle. That's four.

Comment: @KingSaber You would need to rewrite `findNumberOfWaysToMaze` to be recursive rather than iterative, having it branch at every junction, backtrack recursively when it hits a dead end or finds a path, etc.

Comment: Where is the entrance/exit?

Comment: @Patashu, yeah, thanks, thats what I thought. I guess I just counted too fast and did a path twice.

Comment: @Steve P The entrance is 0,0, the exit is 4,4. Both hard coded.

Comment: @King Saber this problem is getting to complex to just write the code and hope it works. What you need to do is to start writing test cases, look at [junit](http://junit.org/) or [testng](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) both are supported by most IDEs

Comment: DFS tends to be cyclic (get stuck in infinite loops), use a mechanism like visited[][] or taboo-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in assuming that your `visitedMap` is causing problems.  The thing is that multiple paths can pass through the same node, so you're getting a result of 2 because there are only two possible positions immediately adjacent to the target.

Unfortunately, your stack as you have implemented it is not capable of unwinding the path of visited points back to what was available at the time each position was added.

This would be much easier for you to implement recursively.  When you enter the function, you mark the point at `(currentX, currentY)` as visited.  When you leave the function, you unmark it.  That will unwind your path correctly.

Your function would be something like this:

```
public int findNumberofWaysToMaze( boolean[][] maze, boolean[][] visitedMap,
                                   int currentX, int currentY, int targetX, int targetY )
{
    if( currentX == targetX && currentY == targetY ) return 1;

    if( currentX < 0 || currentX >= maze.length ) return 0;            // X out of bounds
    if( currentY < 0 || currentY >= maze[currentX].length ) return 0;  // Y out of bounds
    if( visitedMap[currentX][currentY] == true ) return 0;             // Already seen
    if( maze[currentX][currentY] == true ) return 0;                   // Wall

    visitedMap[currentX][currentY] = true;

    int numberofWays = 0;
    numberofWays += findNumberofWaysToMaze(maze, visitedMap, currentX-1, currentY, targetX, targetY );
    numberofWays += findNumberofWaysToMaze(maze, visitedMap, currentX+1, currentY, targetX, targetY );
    numberofWays += findNumberofWaysToMaze(maze, visitedMap, currentX, currentY-1, targetX, targetY );
    numberofWays += findNumberofWaysToMaze(maze, visitedMap, currentX, currentY+1, targetX, targetY );

    visitedMap[currentX][currentY] = false;
    return numberofWays;
}
```

You could of course make that private, and use the original one as a basic wrapper (to create and initialise `visitedMap`).

Comment: Thanks, this is really good! BTW, do I have way to make this non-recursive?

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to add the wall-test.  Have fixed.

Comment: Yeah you can make it non-recursive, but you have to put 'visits' onto a stack somehow.  The recursive method does that automatically, because recursion is already a stack.  I can't think of exactly how to describe it off the top of my head, which is why I suggested that it's *easier* to do it with recursion.